# How can I take BackUp of my phone contact list to google cloud storage?

Tags: android

```
public class BackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
       // The name of the SharedPreferences file
        static final String HIGH_SCORES_FILENAME = "scores";

       // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
        static final String FILES_BACKUP_KEY = "myfiles";
       // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
            FileBackupHelper helper = new FileBackupHelper(this, HIGH_SCORES_FILENAME);
            addHelper(FILES_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
            }       

    public void requestBackup() {
         BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(BackupAgent.this);
          bm.dataChanged();
                 }  
}
```

I am using this code but this is not working. and i dont know where to keep the files which has to be backedup.